# Grid item take as much space at necessary

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to create View as follows:
[image: small left box, right extended box in one row, then second row, one box which takes whole area]

I can only use to achieve that Grid View functionality (no flexbox).

For now I've prepared grid like:

```css
.item1 { grid-area: left; }
.item2 { grid-area: right; }
.item3 { grid-area: content; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'left right'
    'content content';
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 5px;
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">left</div>
  <div class="item2">right</div>
  <div class="item3">content</div>
</div>
```

Here is js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d32phsyu/3/

Where I have left, right and content grid-template-areas.

Problem is that I would like left area to take only as much space as its content (like inline-block) and right area to take all other space.

Is it possible without saying how much pixels left needs to take?

If yes, then how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the column widths with the first as `auto` and the second as `1fr` (the rest of the space).

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: left;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: right;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: content;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right' 'content content';
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">left</div>
  <div class="item2">right</div>
  <div class="item3">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that I've tried it, but that's it. Thanks a lot! It works.